# Alignment issue with div block

Tags: html, css

I've recreated my issues with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/NLLET/)

My date div on the right get moved down if the window becomes too small when re-sized (thinking mobile device view)

**Is it possible to re-size the text area and keep the date div at the top when re-sized?**

I've included two screen showing the issue when re-sized.

Screen 1
[image]

Screen 2 (**re-sized**)

[image]

My current css looks like this:

```
div.thumbnail_image {
float: left;
height: 64px;
position: relative;
width: 64px;
}
.widget-content {
padding: 12px 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
.msg-list {
border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
padding: 10px 12px;
}

.msg-list span {
display:block;
}
.msg-list .msg-date {
display: block;
border: solid 1px #00ff00;
color: #BBBBBB;
float: right;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
text-align: center;
width: 50px;
}
.msg-list .msg-date .msg-month {
display: block;
font-size: 19px;
font-weight: bold;
margin-bottom: -4px;
}
.msg-summary {
border: solid 1px #ff0000;
display: block;
float: left;
max-width: 70%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to remove the `float: left` from `.msg-summary` and give it a margin to the right to reserve the space for the date-div, see http://jsfiddle.net/ZybhC/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such a design by ordering your elements like this:

image
date
text

All you need then is float the image div left, float the date div right, apply margin to the text div equal to the other divs width:

```
.middle {
  float:none;
  margin:0 64px;
}
.date {
  float:right;
}
.msg {
  width:50%;
  min-width:200px;      
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ofevot/1/edit